# Cannot compile Windows msvc with cross-rs and cross-tools from Windows host

Tags: rust

I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline that intends to compile a binary for all OS targets - Windows, MacOS, Linux @ amd64, arm64.

To do this I am using GitHub Actions using the respective host OS to build the binary for the target platform (Linux builds Linux binaries, Windows builds Windows binaries, MacOS builds MacOS binaries).

Linux works fine however I am failing to get Windows to compile binaries for Windows arm64 and amd64 targets.

I assume Windows amd64 cannot build for Windows arm64 directly and there for something like `cross-rs` is necessary for that case - Though I looked and couldn't find a way to compile it directly on the Windows host.

Due to licensing issues, cross-rs does not include prebuilt images for Windows and MacOS platforms and requires the extra cross-toolchains to add those targets. This contains dockerfiles for the builder environments that you must build separately, where you supply legal access to the appropriate compiler toolchain (msvc in this case).

I am attempting to follow [the instructions](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross-toolchains/blob/main/README.md) but am failing - probably on something simple.

My Github Actions host is using `windows-latest` and my build script looks like:

```bash
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
cargo install cross

git clone https://github.com/cross-rs/cross /cross
cd /cross
git submodule update --init --remote

# I have tried with and without the following line
cargo xtask configure-crosstool x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

cargo build-docker-image x86_64-pc-windows-msvc --tag local

# Never gets this far
echo '\n' >> Cargo.toml
echo '[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]\n' >> Cargo.toml
echo 'image = "ghcr.io/cross-rs/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc:local"\n' >> Cargo.toml

cross run --release --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

You can see the logs here: https://github.com/alshdavid-labs/cross-platform-binary-template/actions/runs/5892634303/job/15982367248

This results in the following error:

```
Run git clone https://github.com/cross-rs/cross /cross
Cloning into '/cross'...
Submodule 'docker/cross-toolchains' (https://github.com/cross-rs/cross-toolchains.git) registered for path 'docker/cross-toolchains'
Cloning into 'D:/cross/docker/cross-toolchains'...
Submodule path 'docker/cross-toolchains': checked out '4299096a1468f91aa9a[7](https://github.com/alshdavid-labs/cross-platform-binary-template/actions/runs/5892357823/job/15981437973#step:4:8)430e4763de6[8](https://github.com/alshdavid-labs/cross-platform-binary-template/actions/runs/5892357823/job/15981437973#step:4:9)5cb386a1'
    Updating crates.io index
 Downloading crates ...
  Downloaded same-file v1.0.6
  Downloaded thiserror-impl v1.0.40
   ....
   ....
   ....
   Compiling wildmatch v2.1.1
   Compiling xtask v0.0.0-dev.0 (D:\cross\xtask)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1m 56s
     Running `target\debug\xtask.exe configure-crosstool x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`
Error: 
   0: unable to find config for target "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"

Location:
   xtask\src\crosstool.rs:73

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\xtask.exe configure-crosstool x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` (exit code: 1)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.21s
     Running `target\debug\xtask.exe build-docker-image x86_64-pc-windows-msvc --tag local`
Error: 
   0: unable to find dockerfile for target "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"

Location:
   xtask\src\build_docker_image.rs:105

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\xtask.exe build-docker-image x86_64-pc-windows-msvc --tag local` (exit code: 1)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Am I missing something here?

Or can I just skip cross-rs and target Windows arm64 binaries directly, without needing cross-rs?

Does the same go for MacOS? Can I build arm64 and amd64 binaries from an amd64 Intel Mac host (or vice versa)?

Comment: Nervmind, I don't need to use cross-rs when I arm running on the target host OS. I can just add the toolchain and target it. I am not sure if that will work with more complex applications though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but here is a crate of mine that I build for linux, macos and windows in the CI: https://github.com/Finomnis/tokio-graceful-shutdown/blob/62cd3167cd6fe6e43cfcb76633ae2a03df93c263/.github/workflows/ci.yml
Note that I target it for `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`, though, instead of `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`. Maybe that's what you are missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [list of supported targets](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross#supported-targets), at the time of writing, `cross` does not support `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.

You will have to use `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` instead.

Furthermore, note that the whole point of `cross` is that you do **not** need Windows to build a Windows binary. You can run all of the toolchains on the same system; for CI purposes, I usually use something like `ubuntu-latest`.

As an example, here is a snippet from [one of my own crates](https://github.com/Finomnis/tokio-graceful-shutdown/blob/62cd3167cd6fe6e43cfcb76633ae2a03df93c263/.github/workflows/ci.yml):

```rust
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      RUSTFLAGS: "-D warnings"
    strategy:
      matrix:
        target:
          - aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
          - x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
          - x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install cross
        uses: taiki-e/install-action@cross

      - name: Build
        run: cross build --all-features --all-targets --release --target=${{ matrix.target }}
```

Comment: That's cool thanks. My issue was that I wanted to produce a Windows arm64 binary (and eventually MacOS amd64 and arm64 binaries). The GNU Windows toolchain target does not support arm64 so the msvc target is my only option. Github actions offers Windows and MacOS hosts and I wrongfully assumed that an amd64 Windows/Linux/MacOS host could not target an arm64 target. In the end I solved the issue by adding the appropriate toolchain to the native OS via rustup and building normally. Happy I can now automatically publish my rust projects to all major OSes :)

Comment: My only concern is that with more complicated projects, the arm64 builds will fail on missing arm64 libraries given they are being compiled on an amd64 host.